# how to open the terminal or the command in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just want to enter `ext install typewriter-sounds` to install a plug in. there are many plugins that require similar command. I just dont know where to type that command. 
I dont know what its called.

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio Code or the Visual  Studio? If Code, then `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` should do it

Comment: someone might changed too much on this PC, I tried that and it did nothing. can you tell me how to find it from drop-down menus ?

Comment: `View` -> `Command Pallette`

Answer (score 0):

You can open an integrated terminal with one of the options described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

> Use the Ctrl+` keyboard shortcut with the backtick character.
>   Use the View | Toggle Integrated Terminal menu command.
>   From the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), use the View:Toggle Integrated Terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Please press the:

**ctrl + `**